# inputting a disk file and storing it into both strings and ints

Tags: java, string, int

I am writing a chess program that requires me to input a .txt file with each chess piece already written out like "White Horse 2 7" and storing it as two strings and two ints. Problem I am having is figuring out how to do both strings AND ints and how to do it for each individual piece. I am new at coding and this has me pretty baffled so any help would be great. Thanks!

This is what I have so far

```
 String content = new Scanner(new File("filename")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
 System.out.println(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the flow

1. Open file and pass to Scanner
2. use Scanner.nextLine () to read line into String
3. split String based upon whitespace (returns array)
4. assign array[0] and array[1] to String values
5. assign array[2] and array[3] to int values using Integer.paseInt